# HR Sentence Interpretation for Performance Reviews

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would like to know how this sentence is interpreted by others. My VP of HR has a differing interpretation than the rest of the company, and I need some substance to back up my thought process, or be set correct.

**Absences do not exceed 3 days or 20 hours in partial days.**

Information needed to process - our work day is 8 hours.

I interpret this as an employee cannot miss more than 3 full days (which would be 24 hrs due to our work hours), or no more than 20 hours in partial days (tardies, leaving early unscheduled) in the event they do not have any full days where they have called in to work.

My VP of HR seems to think they cannot miss more than 20 hours... period. I feel that if that is the case, then the sentence should read "Absences do not exceed 20 hours".

Comment: I know I'm being a stickler here, but shouldn't this use the verb _shall_, then?

Comment: And 'partial days' needs clarification, for sure. I agree with you that if the intention was to ban absences greater than 20 hours, then it should clearly state this. I'm afraid that this kind of statement needs a much longer rewrite in order to get the true point across.

Comment: What happens when you miss one or two full days and then some partial days?

Comment: If your VP is correct, then 3 days' absence is already *excessive* (more than 20 hours), and the "not exceed 3 days" phrase makes no sense. I take the sentence to mean that if I missed 3 full days, then I would keep my job providing I had no further absence. If I'd been an hour late 13 times, then 1 day of absence would mean disciplinary action.

Comment: Seems like a case where "clarity" broke everything. This is why contract language is hard. What if there was a 2 hour day that was ended because of a state emergency, another 1 hour day that ended because of a fire, and you miss two full days because, hey, those were some pretty traumatic days with all the fires and stuff. Your VP says you're out, but you say you're good. Here's a better solution: get a better HR policy. That one sounds like something from 1970... or 1984.

Answer (score 2):

The 20 hour maximum interpretation is wrong, because it turns the three-day clause into [surplusage](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surplusage). Generally speaking regulations should be read so that all the clauses are meaningful. **The problem is that this regulation leads to paradoxes.** Is someone who takes two full days and 6 hours of another day in or out of compliance? And I'm not sure how a paradoxical regulation is supposed to be construed. Probably, it should be sent back to the authors, but in the alternative, I would suggest that the best reading is to replace 20 with 24. In California employment regulations are generally construed to the benefit of the employee, and probably most other jurisdictions, but that is speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess, and argue, that the person who wrote that wanted to make sure that if people were going to miss time that was not whole days they would be penalized for the additional disruptions caused by being able to miss less time overall.

Answer (score 0):

Linguistically I don't think there's any way to discern the intent.  Logically it would follow that the two systems should be treated independently from each other since one expresses an entirely more stringent condition than the other (one would always reach the second restriction before hitting up against the first).  Unless there are people who work shifts that are shorter than 8 hours, then it could be different.